Nginx and Docker host names
I'm not sure if what I'm trying is possible but I create Docker containers on the fly and assign them a hostname such as abcde. Each container listens on port 3000 and a random port is assigned on the host (such as 32768).
I also have an Nginx server block that looks like this:
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(?<container>\w+)\.apps\.example\.com$;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://$container;
  }
}

The Nginx reverse proxy is not a Docker container - it is on the host machine.
There is a docker network and each container is on the network. It's a bridge network that I manually created.
The goal is to visit a url such as http://abcde.apps.example.com  and be passed to the docker container with hostname abcde, however this results in a bad gateway error (after waiting until it seems to timeout in the browser).
I'm trying to avoid creating/editing nginx conf files dynamically so I'm hoping that I don't need a port number in the proxy_pass?

Does Nginx need to be a docker container too in order to be able to access the Docker DNS server?

Bad gateway means the response is invalid. Have you considered looking at the response to determine the cause? A simple packet capture should work.

Well it actually doesn't do anything in the browser (just a spinner in the Chrome tab) and eventually times out with a 502. Usually if it's a bad response it would be an instant 502.

To add, I can access the container directly from the web using http://12345.apps.example.com:32768 and I get the expected (correct) response but I don't want to use the port.

You need a mapping name->port, so a DNS based mapping is not possible (DNS doesn't know anything about ports). The closest thing would probably to update a map when creating a new container and trigger a reload in nginx.

Running nginx in a container wouldn't do much good either, AFAIK Docker doesn't have an internal DNS per se, it just creates a hosts file when a container is created. Adding other containers later, while allowing you to use the same port everywhere, would also mean you need to recreate the nginx container every time. Or at least update it's hosts file.

Ok, so this will mean I will need to write to the nginx conf file with a new map each time a container is created and also when a container is deleted it would need to be removed again. Was hoping some nice use of variables would be a solution here. Might have to rethink.

Well, nginx is VERY extensible. You could certainly write a lua script or something like that to implement dynamic mapping.
